# How flink handle unused keyed state field when we update our job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a job which all the user feature and information are stored in keyed state. Each user feature represents a state descriptor. But we are evolving our features so sometimes some features are abandoned in our next release/version because we will no longer declare the abandoned feature state's descriptor in our code. My question is how flink takes care of those abandoned state? Will it no longer restore those abandoned state automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flink POJOs or Avro types, then Flink will automatically migrate the types and state for you. Otherwise, it will not, and you could implement a custom serializer instead. Or you could use the State Processor API to clean things up.